# Using Gödel's incompleteness theorems to strengthen a proof system

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I've recently been looking at Gödel's incompleteness theorems from a very different angle. I'm not new to these theorems at all, but this is a different perspective which I haven't seen posted here before and wanted to ask about it.

The basic idea is this: we treat so-called "first-order PA" as an incomplete, yet sound and effective proof system for second-order PA. It's not quite the same as something like Henkin semantics: here, we really do interpret the second-order quantifiers as literally quantifying over *all* first-order predicates, but our proof system only has the ability to substitute in a first-order definable predicate into a second-order sentence and make whatever inferences one can be derive from that. The first incompleteness theorem then shows that this proof system is incomplete and cannot prove everything that is true in second-order PA. The second incompleteness theorem shows that any proof system for second-order PA which *is* complete is either not sound or not effective.

This perspective leads to some very interesting viewpoints. For instance, the Gödel sentence can be interpreting as saying that the proof system in question is not strong enough to prove the sentence. In other words, the proof system is not strong enough to prove its own lack of strength. We may then ask how we know this sentence is true, and of course the answer is that we *don't*: if we have inadvertently created an inconsistent theory, the sentence will in fact be false. What we do know is that *if and only if* the second-order theory is consistent and the proof system is sound, then the sentence is in fact true. Given these *additional assumptions*, we can then prove the Gödel sentence. In fact, the second incompleteness theorem is basically this, but where we formulate these new additional assumptions in a simpler way (directly asserting there is no natural number encoding a proof of 1=0).

But this is *extremely* bizarre, because it can be thought of giving us a way to strengthen our proof system "for free!" Basically, what we're saying is, if we start with our second-order proof system, we can simply add an additional inference rule basically stating "we assume this proof system to be sound" and somehow we can then magically prove more theorems which are guaranteed to be true in the second-order theory. This seems nuts.

One question is: does this mean it's a *theorem* of second-order PA that our proof system is sound? Or a theorem of second-order PA that second-order PA is consistent? Or at least the Gödel-encoded versions of these things? I'm not sure how to make sense of this.

EDIT: Noah Schweber has given some really good insights below into why a first-order perspective is probably a much cleaner way to look at this than the second-order proof-system above. In that view, this question can be rewritten as: when I add $Con(T)$ to some logical theory $T$, why does that really make it stronger? And in what "direction" is it strengthening the theory, rather than adding $~Con(T)$? When does it tend to point things towards a particular choice of "standard model" and why? I've left this question open though as I am also interested in the second-order view (even if it's more limited).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure I understand your overall goal *(how does this differ from just the usual first-order "iterated consistency extensions"? why do you say that the second incompleteness theorem, rather than the first, is the one that "shows that any proof system for second-order PA which is complete is either not sound or not effective"? and a couple other confusions)*. However, focusing on the end of your post, I think the following is important:

> Unlike first-order $\mathsf{PA}$, second-order $\mathsf{PA}$ (call it "$\mathsf{PA_2}$") **cannot** talk about its own logical consequences.

More concretely, and abbreviating $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ (or similar) by just "$\mathbb{N}$," the set of second-order tautologies (in particular, the set of tautologous second-order *implications*) in the language of arithmetic isn't a definable-in-$\mathsf{SOL}$ subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (under an appropriate coding system). This is an immediate consequence of three facts:

- The **finiteness** of $\mathsf{PA_2}$ (no need for an induction *scheme*!).
- The **categoricity** of $\mathsf{PA}_2$ (no nonstandard models!).
- **Tarski's undefinability theorem** (which while usually stated for first-order logic applies more generally).

Let $\varphi$ be the one-second-order-sentence axiomatization of $\mathsf{PA_2}$. Then by the first two bulletpoints above we get $$Th_{\mathsf{SOL}}(\mathbb{N})=\{\psi:\emptyset\models_{\mathsf{SOL}}\varphi\rightarrow\psi\},$$ but the third says that $Th_{\mathsf{SOL}}(\mathbb{N})$ isn't second-order definable in $\mathbb{N}$.

Consequently, we can't even ask in $\mathsf{PA_2}$ whether $\mathsf{PA_2}$ is satisfiable.

Comment: It differs from the usual first order consistency extensions because if we use first order PA, we have PA + Con(PA) is stronger than PA, and PA + ~Con(PA) is also stronger than PA. Both are first order non-conservative extensions of PA. But only the first one is a sub theory of second order PA, so adding the encoded "this theory is consistent" sentence lets us prove more theorems from the second order theory, which literally translates into proving more things about various Diophantine equations and such. (1/2)

Comment: This seems like magic -- if I take the first order theory of, I dunno, let's say rings, for instance, can I add an additional axiom encoding "this theory is consistent" and now somehow magically prove more stuff about rings? After all you can characterize the integers within the theory of rings, and categorize the naturals within those, and so I guess you would be able to still build a Gödel numbering and etc. (2/2)

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I still don't understand what second-order logic in any form has to do with anything; I think you're just asking about the general way that a theory $T$ (in this case, first-order $\mathsf{PA}$) can be nontrivially strengthened simply by adding "obvious" correctness facts about $T$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, and strengthened in such a way that the "standard model" is still a model of the theory, if one is philosophically willing to admit such a thing as a standard model exists. It seems like there is a big difference between adding Con(T) and ~Con(T) to some theory T. But mostly I am trying to figure out, for instance, to what theories I can "strengthen" by adding Con(T) that way and what I am really doing when I do.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia OK, in that case I think it's simpler to drop reference to second-order logic and just talk about a first-order theory with a distinguished model. Note that even before we get to the idea of referring to $T$'s "true" properties inside the language of $T$, the distinguished model is doing a ton of conceptual heavy lifting: when you ask (say) about the theory of rings, what "distinguished ring" do you have in  mind here?

Comment: Separately, I think "if I take the first order theory of, I dunno, let's say rings, for instance, can I add an additional axiom encoding "this theory is consistent" and now somehow magically prove more stuff about rings" misses the point: if we have a way of encoding "this theory is consistent" as a sentence in the relevant language, then that sentence **is already** an example of "more stuff about rings" that it entails. The magic is in the existence of a "satisfactory" encoding process, not in the *(literally true by definition)* fact that encoded meta-statements are object-level statements.

Comment: On that note, I think the right thing to look to here is an **interpretation**. Broadly speaking, given a (finite) language $L$ there is a structure $\mathcal{L}$ which more-or-less describes "first-order $L$-syntax." If we have a distinguished structure $\mathcal{M}$ of interest, we can ask whether there is an interpretation $\Phi$ of $\mathcal{L}$ into $\mathcal{M}$. If the answer is yes, and if $T$ is a theory satisfied by $\mathcal{M}$ which is "sufficiently easy to describe" (e.g. finite) as a subset of $\mathcal{L}$, then we can use $\Phi$ to encode things in a natural way. (cont'd)

Comment: Of course, a priori this all depends on the choice of $\Phi$. So really we additionally want there to be some $\sigma$ satisfied by $\mathcal{M}$ which ensures that any two interpretations of $\mathcal{L}$ into $\mathcal{M}$ are "definably isomorphic." At this point we can ignore the choice of interpretation (this is basically why the choice of Godel numbering doesn't really matter, up to logical equivalence, in producing the Godel sentence).

Comment: OK, I think I get what you're saying. The only thing I don't get, about generalizing this, is that typically theories really don't have one standard model. In first-order ZFC, for instance, I don't get the sense that people have one idea about many large cardinals the "standard model" should have. But I do think most people would agree that if you take first-order ZFC and add ~Con(ZFC) to it, *all* of the models of the resulting theory will be pathological in some sense (I think they'll probably all not be well founded). But your point about the "magic" being in the encoding is well taken.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Yes, the more general approach is to consider a "complicated" class of nice structures living inside a "simple" class of generally-annoying structures; e.g. the class of well-founded models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ living inside the class of all models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (the latter is an elementary class but the former isn't). Re: models of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)}$, indeed they are not even $\omega$-models (assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is "truly" transitive of course!), so they're a fortiori non-well-founded.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I see you've accepted my answer, even though - per the comment thread - it turns out I wasn't actually addressing your question. Would you like me to update the answer to reflect the comments?

Comment: I think the thing I was looking for was basically this "if we have a way of encoding "this theory is consistent" as a sentence in the relevant language, then that sentence is already an example of "more stuff about rings" that it entails. The magic is in the existence of a "satisfactory" encoding process, not in the (literally true by definition) fact that encoded meta-statements are object-level statements." I think that clarifies for me what kind of "information" we are adding to the theory when we add its own encoded consistency as an axiom, so it isn't really quite "magic."

Comment: I still am kind of interested in the second order perspective, so if you think it's better to leave it open for other answers I can do that...

Comment: I've added a note clarifying the first-order view of things is probably better. I think maybe best is to just "upvote" your answer and leave it open in case anyone wants to go further into the second-order thing, even if it's limited.